# Rank by gaps in data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame there I have identified row that have wrong/missing data.

I need to count consecutive missing values. What I am missing is a function that can rank, but rank restarts at each gap and increments with each consecutive gap.

Basically my data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-02-10") + 1:10, Missing = c(F,F,T,F,T,T,T,F,T,T))
```

I want to get this:

```
data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-02-10") + 1:10, Missing = c(F,F,T,F,T,T,T,F,T,T),
           Rank = c(0,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1,2))
#          Date Missing Rank
# 1  2017-02-11   FALSE    0
# 2  2017-02-12   FALSE    0
# 3  2017-02-13    TRUE    1
# 4  2017-02-14   FALSE    0
# 5  2017-02-15    TRUE    1
# 6  2017-02-16    TRUE    2
# 7  2017-02-17    TRUE    3
# 8  2017-02-18   FALSE    0
# 9  2017-02-19    TRUE    1
# 10 2017-02-20    TRUE    2
```

I am familiar with `dplyr` and I tried using `cummax` but that does not restart count, I don't know how to reset it to zero:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Rank = if_else(Missing == T, cummax(Rank), 0))
```

I'm starting to wonder if this will require a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the cumulative sum of the `Missing` column, *grouped by* the cumulative sum of all the `FALSE` values:

```
library(dplyr)   
test.df %>% group_by(group = cumsum(Missing == FALSE)) %>% 
    mutate(Rank = cumsum(Missing))
#         Date Missing group  Rank
#       <date>   <lgl> <int> <int>
#1  2017-02-11   FALSE     1     0
#2  2017-02-12   FALSE     2     0
#3  2017-02-13    TRUE     2     1
#4  2017-02-14   FALSE     3     0
#5  2017-02-15    TRUE     3     1
#6  2017-02-16    TRUE     3     2
#7  2017-02-17    TRUE     3     3
#8  2017-02-18   FALSE     4     0
#9  2017-02-19    TRUE     4     1
#10 2017-02-20    TRUE     4     2
```

This works because boolean values are represented as `0`'s and `1`'s under the hood.

Comment: Alternately, `Rank = row_number() - 1L`

Comment: Wow it would never occur to me to build such groups. This works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Rank := cumsum(Missing), rleid(Missing)]

df
#          Date Missing Rank
# 1: 2017-02-11   FALSE    0
# 2: 2017-02-12   FALSE    0
# 3: 2017-02-13    TRUE    1
# 4: 2017-02-14   FALSE    0
# 5: 2017-02-15    TRUE    1
# 6: 2017-02-16    TRUE    2
# 7: 2017-02-17    TRUE    3
# 8: 2017-02-18   FALSE    0
# 9: 2017-02-19    TRUE    1
#10: 2017-02-20    TRUE    2
```